# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el tipo de una columna en postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, casting

Estoy con **postgresql** y como editor **Dbeaver 7**. Tengo una tabla "viajes_csv" donde he cargado datos de un archivo **csv**.
Las columnas son estas:
gid(numeric),ts(text),direccion(text), hwid(numeric), latfin(text), lonfin(text), carga(numeric),autonomia(numeric),viaje(tet), tiempoviaje(numeric), consumo(numeric), distancia(numeric), recarga(text), latini(text), lonini(text)

Después creo otra tabla "viajes" donde metere algunos campos de la anterior y añadiré unos nuevos con cálculos sobre los anteriores.
Las columnas son estas:
gid(int4), ts(text), hwid(numeric), carga(numeric), tiempoviaje(numeric), recarga(text), latini(bigint), lonini(bigint), latfin(bigint), lonfin(bigint), geomini(geometry), geomini_25830(geometry), geomfin(geometry), geomfin_25830(geometry).

Al cargar los datos, las seis primeras columnas son de la la tabla inicial, las cuatro sigientes hay que cambiarlas de tipo text a bigint, y las cuatro ultimas son tipo geometria que las creo con calculos de las anteriores.

El problema me lo da el último select, que es primero en realizarse y me da un error "SQL Error [22P02]: ERROR: la sintaxis de entrada no es válida para tipo integer: «41,672024».

Esta es la consulta que hago:

```
 insert into datos.viajes (ts, hwid, carga, tiempoviaje, recarga, latini, lonini, latfin, lonfin, geomini, geomfin, geomini_25830, geomfin_25830)
select
    ts, hwid, carga, tiempoviaje, recarga, latini, lonini, latfin, lonfin, geomini, geomfin,
    ST_Transform(geomini,25830)::geometry(Point,25830) as geomini_25830,
    ST_Transform(geomfin,25830)::geometry(Point,25830) as geomfin_25830
from
    (select
        ts, hwid, carga, tiempoviaje, recarga, latini, lonini, latfin, lonfin,
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lonini, latini),4326)::geometry(Point,4326) as geomini,
        ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(lonfin, latfin),4326)::geometry(Point,4326) as geomfin
    from
        (select

            ts, hwid, (latfin)::bigint,
            (lonfin)::bigint,
            carga, tiempoviaje, recarga,
            (latini)::bigint,
            (lonini)::bigint

        from 
            (select
                vc.*

            from
                datos.viajes_csv vc

            ) as foo
        )as foo
    where
        lonini is not null
    ) as foo;
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: procura incluir siempre en tus preguntas de SQL, la definición de tus tablas. Hará más fácil revisar la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Al final la consulta esta bien.
El problema estaba en el archivo origen que tenía cambiados los puntos decimales por comas.
Gracias